# How Windows check radius server certificate?

Tags: windows, certificate, radius

How Windows check radius server certificate (for wifi connections)? Does it look only on CN field from radius server certificate and not look at Subject Alternative Name field altogether?

I did some tests, and Windows accept radius server certificate only if CN field from certificate match with value in field "Connect to these servers:" [Windows certificate validation properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQY5A.png)

Other Operation Systems look at Subject Alternative Name field from certificate.

Answer (score 0):

I stand corrected. You found the RFC that states CN *should* be evaluated last: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6125#page-28. Whether or not the client is properly implementing this to the RFC spec is a different matter.

Comment: By my tests iOS and wpa_supplicant (Android) use Subject Alternative Names.
RFC 6125 Chapter 6.4.4 https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6125#page-28 says what client should check CN as a last resort.